# Hidden column when exporting to Excel from SSRS despite using points

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Like many people, I have trouble sometimes with exporting to Excel from SSRS: hidden or split columns appear. Up to now, I have found that using multiples of 18 points works very well. However, I have found an exception to this rule.

If I create a tablix with one column 864 (12 x 72) points wide and a second column 72 points wide, I get a hidden column C. If, instead, the first column of my tablix is 936 (13 x 72) points wide, and the second column is still 72 points wide, I do not get any hidden columns.

I've looked in the .rdl file and there's nothing hidden in there like headers or footers. My page width is 210mm. I tried changing it to 150mm just to see if there was any difference but there wasn't.

Changing the second column of the first report to 73pt (so it's now 864pt and 73pt) eliminates the hidden column C. So does changing the second column to 25mm. So I may just have to fiddle with the column widths, but I would like to know why the rule of using multiples of 18 points doesn't work in this situation.

Screenshot added at the request of niktrs:
[image]
You can see that column N is hidden. It has zero width.

Comment: A screenshot with the report layout would help us understand about column splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that editing the RDL file in Notepad, and towards the end of the Tablix section, changing the line `<Width>330.2mm</Width>` to 936pt worked. That is, there is no longer a hidden column C when exporting. As 936/72 * 25.4 = 330.2, I don't know why Report Builder didn't convert the measurement in mm to an exact number of points, but I don't mind, as I now have a report that exports correctly. I also found that right at the end of the RDL file, there is a line `<rd:ReportUnitType>Mm</rd:ReportUnitType>`. Changing 'Mm' to 'Point' seems to enable me to type measurements in using points and have Report Builder store them as points instead of converting them to mm.